# Local variable output in a function surprises me

Tags: python

The following program:

```
a_var = 10
b_var = 15
e_var = 25

def a_func(a_var):

    print "in a_func a_var = ",a_var
    b_var = 100 + a_var
    d_var = 2*a_var
    print "in a_func b_var = ",b_var
    print "in a_func d_var = ",d_var
    print "in a_func e_var = ",e_var
    return b_var + 10

c_var = a_func(b_var)
```

Prints this output:

> in a_func a_var =  15
>   in a_func b_var =  115
>   in a_func d_var =  30
>   in a_func e_var =  25

I'm unsure why the "in a_func a_var" is equal to 15 and not 10.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should take a look at [variable scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) to understand why things work this way; passed-in parameters will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the parameter to your function is called `a_var` and this hides the global variable.

You call the function as `a_func(b_var)` so the argument has the value 15.

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes `a_var` as a parameter; this 'overrides' the global value. Since you pass the value of `b_var` (15) to the function, it sees `a_var` as 15.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to see with this simplified case

```
A = 10
B = 15

def foo(A):
    print A # prints 15

foo(B)
```